# DateTime format not working

Tags: php

I'm trying to format a date and it's not working?

```
$date = new DateTime('23/09/2012 08:12:14 AM');
echo $date->format('l, dS F Y, H:i:s A');
```

Any hints?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `createFromFormat`:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y h:i:s A', '23/09/2012 08:12:14 AM');
echo $date->format('l, dS F Y, H:i:s A');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$result = mysql_query("SELECT `datetime` FROM `table`");
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
$date = date_create($row[0]);

echo date_format($date, 'Y-m-d H:i:s');
#output: 2012-03-24 17:45:12

echo date_format($date, 'd/m/Y H:i:s');
#output: 24/03/2012 17:45:12

echo date_format($date, 'd/m/y');
#output: 24/03/12

echo date_format($date, 'g:i A');
#output: 5:45 PM

echo date_format($date, 'G:ia');
#output: 05:45pm

echo date_format($date, 'g:ia \o\n l jS F Y');
#output: 5:45pm on Saturday 24th March 2012

?>
```

try to refer this site....will be helpfull

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: What does mysql stuff has to do with this question?

Comment: @Havelock: date_format() [procedural style] function is alias of DateTime::format() [object oriented style], so your statement is not true.

Comment: This is a copy-paste from here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php